# Iterate over a cursor

Tags: loops, stored-procedures, cursor, teradata

I'd like to create a cursor or a table from a select statement using rows of another cursor as a parameter. In my example, I got a temporal table with one column and multiples rows. Those rows should be the entry of the next select and show (or save) the results.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE test (IN name_db VARCHAR(25), IN name_table VARCHAR(25), IN n INT)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
DECLARE a VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE b VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE qry VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE prindx VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE p VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE idx VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE diff VARCHAR(32000);
DECLARE csr1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR stmt1;

SET a = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT ColumnName AS col1 FROM DBC.Columns WHERE DatabaseName=''' ||name_db || ''' AND TableName=''' || name_table || ''') A1 ';
SET b = 'WHERE ';

SET i=1;
WHILE i <=N DO
   BEGIN
      CASE i
      WHEN 1 THEN
         SET qry = a;
         SET prindx = 'SELECT (col1';
      WHEN 2 THEN
         SET a = a || 'CROSS JOIN (SELECT ColumnName AS col' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2)) || ' FROM DBC.Columns WHERE DatabaseName='''||name_db || ''' AND TableName=''' || name_table || ''') A' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2)) || ' ';
         SET b = b || 'A' || CAST((i-1) AS VARCHAR(2)) || '.col' || CAST((i-1) AS VARCHAR(2)) || ' < A'  || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2)) || '.col' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2));
         SET qry a || b;
         SET prindx = prindx || ' || '','' || col' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2));
      ELSE
         SET a = a || 'CROSS JOIN (SELECT ColumnName AS col' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2)) || ' FROM DBC.Columns WHERE DatabaseName='''||name_db || ''' AND TableName=''' || name_table || ''') A' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2)) || ' ';
         SET b = b || ' AND A' || CAST((i-1) AS VARCHAR(2)) || '.col' || CAST((i-1) AS VARCHAR(2)) || ' < A'  || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2)) || '.col' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2));
         SET qry a || b;
         SET prindx = prindx || ' || '','' || col' || CAST(i AS VARCHAR(2));
      END CASE;
      SET i = i + 1;
   END;
END WHILE;

   BEGIN
      DECLARE exit HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
      BEGIN
         IF SQLCODE <> 3807 THEN RESIGNAL; END IF;
      END;
      SET p = name_db || '.tbl1 ';
      DROP TABLE p;
   END;

SET p = 'CREATE TABLE ' || name_db || '.tbl1 AS (' || qry || ') WITH DATA';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p;

SET prindx = prindx || ') AS PRYINDX FROM ' || name_db || '.tbl1 ';

PREPARE stmt1 FROM prindx;
OPEN csr1;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FETCH csr1 INTO idx;

SET diff = 'SELECT (MAX(A.TOTAL) - MIN(A.TOTAL)) AS DIFF 
FROM (SELECT HASHAMP(HASHBUCKET(HASHROW(' || idx || '))) CODHASH, CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(18,0) TOTAL 
FROM ' || name_db || '.' || name_table || ' GROUP BY 1) A';
```

I'd like to use the values of "csr1" inside the Select statement above and take all possible results. For now, I just can take the last one.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please edit the question to clarify what error you are seeing or what you are having difficulty with. Also, fix some obvious typos in the initial post: SELEECT -> SELECT and CROS JOIN -> CROSS JOIN.

Comment: I just want to replace each row of the cursor "csr1" like "idx" in the last SELECT Statement and save the results. For now, I just can get one.

Comment: Because you are dynamically supplying column, table, and database names you need to build the SQL statement as a string and execute it dynamically. It seems you have started to do that. And since that statement is a SELECT, you would need to PREPARE it (as stmt2?) and use a second dynamic cursor (csr2?) to fetch the value of DIFF.